# sketching and domain question

Tags: complex-analysis

Sketch the region in the complex plane given by $|z+i|<2$, with Im$z<0$, and decide whether this region is a domain or not.

So correct me if I am wrong but would the combined region be $S=${$z\in\mathbb{C}:|z+i|<2$, Im$z<0$}? Now how do I decide if S is open? Can I just assume that S is open because if I sketch it, it is like 3 quarters of a circle towards the bottom with $(0,-i)$ being the centre and you can see that all the points are interior making S open. 
How do I show that S is connected since that is what decides if S is a domain right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb R$ prescribed by $z\mapsto|z+i|$ is continuous so the preimage under $f$ of open set $(-\infty,2)$ is open.

The function $g:\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb R$ prescribed by $z\mapsto Im(z)$ is continuous so the preimage under $g$ of open set $(-\infty,0)$ is open.

$S$ is the intersection of these open sets, hence is open.

Comment: what about showing that it is connected? because that is what makes it a domain right? open and connected

Comment: Look at the sketch. Clearly path-connected isn't it? That implies connected.

Comment: oh so we can just assume it is connected by the diagram

Comment: That's not what I am saying. The sketch must *inspire* you to find a proof of the existence of a path in $S$ connecting two points in $S$. "Look at the sketch" must be interpreted as "get inspired".

Comment: yeah it seems obvious, if you pick any arbitrary points within S, you would be able to join them with a polygonal path. but I don't get how that is proving it...

Comment: You could prove that both preimages are convex: if $Im(u)<0$ and $Im(v)<0$ then also $Im(tu+(1-t)v)<0$ for each $t\in[0,1]$. Also a ball is convex. Then the intersection $S$ is convex and a path from $u\in S$ to $v\in S$  can be defined as $t\mapsto tu+(1-t)v$ for $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Wait the definition of it being a domain is that uf S is connected and open right? But this S is simply connected isnt it because you can pick any two points inside the region and shrik it to a point. Doesn't that mean its not a domain since it is simplly connected and not connected?

Comment: I mean you can pick a closed polygonal path and shrik it to a point staying inside the region.

Comment: A [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(mathematical_analysis)) in this context is open and connected. As shown in my answere $S$ is open. As shown in my comment $S$ is convex and we have convex $\Rightarrow$ path-connected $\Rightarrow$ connected. The concept of "simply-connected" is not relevant here. You only deal with topology and not with algebraic topology. In short: $S$ is open and connected, and that is what you were asking for.